# Laravel - Store data in HasMany relationship from a multi-select form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, one-to-many

A user can select multiple options:

```
<!-- Select Multiple -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bedrooms">Bedrooms</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="bedrooms" name="bedrooms[]" class="form-control"
                multiple="multiple">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">Studio</option>
          <option value="2">1</option>
          <option value="3">2</option>
          <option value="4">3</option>
          <option value="5">4</option>
          <option value="6">5</option>
          <option value="7">6+</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to store these variables in a table - `bedrooms`, on separate rows so I can include them in queries. Each bedroom will be associated with `criteria_id`:

[image: Structure]

I have tried to use such queries as `$criteria->bedrooms()->saveMany(Input::get('property_type'));` as shown in Laravel's documentation, but to no success - error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save()
must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given
```

and `$criteria->bedrooms()->attach(Input::get('property_type'));` but this returns the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()`

Relation:

`Criteria` -

```
public function bedrooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Bedroom');
    }
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: what error is being produced if any?

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given

Comment: Why `$criteria->properties()`? Shouldn't it be `$criteria->bedrooms()`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, my apologies, I copied it from the wrong line. I'm wanting to do the exact same thing to my properties table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saveMany` will work in this scenario, you just need to convert your input array to a set of new Models first. Assuming you know the Criteria ID, try this:

```
    foreach (Input::get('bedrooms') as $bedroom) {
        $selected[] = New Bedroom(['bedroom' => $bedroom]);
    }
    $criteria = Criteria::find($criteria_id)->bedrooms()->saveMany($selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

The saveMany() method expects an array of models, not id's

Comment: I have also tried `attach()`, which produces`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()`. How would you recommend I save this? Surely there is a simple solution to this?

Comment: Bedroom::whereIn('id', Input::get('bedrooms'))->update(['criteria_id' => Input::get('criteria_id'));

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the query runs but the bedrooms selected aren't saved into the `bedroom` table. DD(query) returns `int(0)`.

Comment: I mean you may need to modify the query ... I dont know what your form, models, and tables look like in their entirety. Are you editing or creating entries on the bedrooms table?

Comment: Your code was perfect minus the criteria_id. I changed it to get a variable - `Bedroom::whereIn('id', Input::get('bedrooms'))->update(['criteria_id' => $criteria_id]);`, this is the example that returns `int(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use checkboxes at view :

```
@foreach($bedrooms as $row)
<input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">{{$row->name}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

Make BedroomCriteria at the Model..
Like this

```
class BedroomCriteria extends Eloquent {
    public function Bedroom() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Bedroom');
    }

    public function Criteria() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Criteria');
    }

}
```

Then The save code at controller is like this

```
  if (isset($input["bedrooms"])) {
                foreach ($input['bedrooms'] as $check) {
                    $bedroom_criteria = array(
                        "bedroom_id" => $check,
                        "criteria_id" => $input['id']
                    );
                    $bedroom_criteria= BedroomCriteria::create($bedroom_criteria);
                }
            }
```